# Как с помощью jquery на аяксе подгрузить виджет facebook?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, xhtml, javascript, html

Как с помощью методов load() или $.ajax подгрузить к себе на сайт виджет фейсбука, например, [этот](http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Ffacebook.com%2Fbmw&width=255&colorscheme=light&show_faces=true&locale=en_US&stream=false&header=false&height=257&border-style=none), чтобы избавиться от фрейма, который грузит виджет обычно.

Answer (score 1):

Смотрите [jquery fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). Много примеров. Надеюсь, найдете то, что надо.